# Objective C iOS WKWebView Background

Tags: objective-c, background, uiwebview, wkwebview

Hopefully someone can help.

I've got an application that currently uses the UIWebview to play audio, which works even if the device is locked as I enable mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay.

However I started to move the code to use the new WKWebView and I've enabled mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay, However when I press the lock button, the WebView stops playing the audio.

Any ideas how I can get WKWebview to behave like the UIWebView?

Update, Here's an example of my code:

```
   WKUserContentController *wkUController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];

theConfiguration.userContentController = wkUController;
theConfiguration.allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = YES;

webViewActive = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:viewForWeb.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
webViewActive.navigationDelegate = self;
webViewActive.frame = viewForWeb.bounds;
[webViewActive setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[viewForWeb addSubview:webViewActive];

NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL TO AUDIO"];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];

[webViewActive loadRequest:nsrequest];
```

Thanks

Comment: Try adding audio background mode to your application.

Comment: I've got audio mode ticked in the capabilities screen.

Comment: in WKWebView you enabled mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay via the settings you initialize the WKWebView with ?

Comment: is there any Solution?